# Tournament bracket customized algorithm

Tags: php, algorithms

I'm in the making of a tournament for archery but i'm stuck because they want a specific match-matching for players. There is the usual 1-32,2-31,3-30 etc but the way they want the tree is a specific one.

For now i'm producing the array with this

```
$players = range(1, $range);
$count = count($players);
for ($i = 0; $i < log($count / 2, 2); $i++) {
    echo $i;
    echo '<br>';
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($players);
    print "</pre>";
    $out = array();
    foreach ($players as $player) {
        $splice = pow(2, $i);

        $out = array_merge($out, array_splice($players, 0, $splice));

        $out = array_merge($out, array_splice($players, -$splice));
    }

    $players = $out;
}
```

With an output of

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 9
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 13
    [6] => 5
    [7] => 12
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 15
    [10] => 7
    [11] => 10
    [12] => 3
    [13] => 14
    [14] => 6
    [15] => 11
)
```

Everything works great except they want the tree like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 16
    [2] => 9
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 12
    [6] => 13
    [7] => 4
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 14
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 6
    [12] => 7
    [13] => 10
    [14] => 15
    [15] => 2
)
```

You will notice some differences between those to.
For example 2-15 match is at position 8 and 9 of the array while in the second one it's at 14-15.

I've been busting my head to find an algorithm for this but i'm stuck.

Thanks

Comment: If they can't express the requirements to you any more clearly than giving an explicit list of pairings, then there is no better solution than implementing it as an explicit list. Don't try to outguess a client too early. Once they see the complete tree you come up with, they *may* understand better what it is they want.

Comment: First thing i did was created the arrays myself and did the pairing. So according to the No of players i choose the "right" array. That's the thing though, they can't understand that, their approach is more like we want exactly this. I guess i'll have to stick with premade arrays rather than producing them dyanamically.

Comment: @TerisL So ask them what the array would be in the case of 8 players, 4 players.. 7 players..  Explain to them that it would be like providing a single number and asking them what the next number in the pattern is.  Regardless of whether or not they understand, the reality is this.  *Don't write a single line of code* until they provide better specifications.

Comment: I agree with the others, in the absence of a general algorithm that scales with inputs it is not possible to implement this except by hard-coding values. In general, brackets are structured to give favorable matchups to the top seeds. This one appears to work differently, but I am at a loss to explain how.